# How do I perform a parity check in python?

Tags: python, bin

I am trying to build a parity check program that scans 8-bits (python) for bit flips. I am not familiar with binary code and have some questions I was hoping someone would be able to answer here.

1. How do I check the parity bit to get a boolean? Can I use splicing on binary data (it keeps giving me an error when I try but so does the variable, and some other things)?
2. How do I store binary data in a variable? When I do `x = 11110000`, it gives an error.

Comment: `x = 0b11110000` or `x=0xf0`.  Note that this is not STORING binary data in a variable.  The data is always binary.  This is just writing a binary constant.

Comment: The easy way to do a parity program is to write an array of 256 entries with the parity value for each entry, and do a simple lookup.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the easy way to build up an 8-bit parity lookup table:

```
paritymap = [ 0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4 ]
popcount = [p+q for q in paritymap for p in paritymap]
print(popcount)

def parity(n):
    return popcount(n) & 1
```